# In a Laravel Model's relationship how do I return a relationship using GROUP BY and MAX?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have a project, the project can have attached documents. Both projects and documents are models/tables.

Simplified example documents table:

```
-----------------------------------
| ID  | filename        | version |
-----------------------------------
| 1   | list.docx       | 1       |
| 2   | list.docx       | 2       |
| 3   | file.xls        | 1       |
-----------------------------------
```

I want to have some simple version control so that if a user wants to they can 'replace' the document, with the new table row copying all of the previous entries values except for ID and version.

My issue is that I want to use a relationship to pull out all of the latest documents. I'm currently using this monstrosity in the Project model:

```
public function latest_documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Document::class)
        ->where('version', \DB::raw('(SELECT max(d.version) from documents d where d.filename = documents.filename)'))
}
```

There must be a better way? I tried just using groupBy() and max() with the relationship but got errors.

EDIT: Attempted 'Laravel method' before the DB::raw solution:

```
public function documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Document::class)->groupBy('filename')->max('version');
}
```

Error:

```
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

Comment: Please post the query with `groupBy()` you tried.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir done, not that I think it helps much! Can't seem to figure out how to group up rows and then select the one with the highest/max version

Comment: did you try `$query->orderBy('version', 'desc')->groupBy('filename');`

Comment: @rkj Nets this error: `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'app.documents.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: can you add `'strict' => false` in `config/database.php` ? and then try

Comment: @rkj Okay that stops the error however it is not returning the max version number of a document, instead it is returning the first entry in the DB. Fairly sure that merely sorting does not correspond to always returning what you would normally expect to be the top sorted result when using groupBy.

Comment: Why do you want to use a relationship? For eager loading?

Answer (score 1):

My advise is to create a MySQL view based on documents table that always contains only latest document files and simply make a relation to that view. So :

Step-1/ create the view :

```
create view latest_documents as
  select filename,
         max(version)  as version,
         project_id    as project_id,
         any_value(id) as id
  from documents
  group by project_id, filename;
```

Step-2/ create the view model :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class LatestDocument extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Step-3/ add the relation to the project model :

```
public function latest_documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LatestDocument::class);
}
```

I tested this and should work.

note: I used `any_value()` in step one to prevent errors according to `only_full_group_by`. So if you disabled this mode(I would not recommend) there is no need to use this function around the `id`.

Comment: The result of this is that the query finds the max version number from the documents table and then returns only documents with that version.

Comment: @MikeK Then what exactly do you try to do with max version in this relationship?
Do you want to sort documents by it?

Comment: I want to find the entry for each file that has the highest version number, and then return those results. Between DB entries however only the file version and ID would change (and other fields like created_at etc).

Comment: @MikeK My advise is to create a MySQL view based on documents table that always contains only latest document files and simply make a relation to that view.

Comment: @MikeK I edited my answer here. Please check it if it's works.